# How to install the Visual Studio 2022 behind the proxy?

Tags: visual-studio, proxy

I am trying to install the visual studio behind a corporate environment but no luck
I have tried changing the machine.config as below at both the below places :
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config and C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config

as below at the end just before the `</configuration>` TAG

```
<configuration>
..
..
..

    <system.net>
      <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />
</system.net>
</configuration>
```

But on launching the VisualStudioSetup or the vs_proffessional I always get the below screen which never moves forward.

[image: Window Stuck]

There was a release note in the Visual Studio which states that it uses the default proxy but seems like it is not taking?
Is there any way to install the Visual Studio behind the proxy?
Where to state the proxy address?
I seem to stuck in this for a week but no resolutions so far !